# What saved in Android app "Data" under Storage?

Tags: android, android-fragments, adview, application-data, application-size

My app uses Fragments, SQLite Database, SharedPreferences and SavedInstanceState to keep the state. 
The problem is that the **Data** size does not stop increasing (about 100-300kB) on each Fragment launch. I can not count on **Clear Data** as long as it removes all data including SQLite Database of the application.

1- What are data of android application saved in Settings> Apps >App info> STORAGE> Data? **OK** (tnx to artworkad シ reply)

2- How this problem can be solved? (while SQLite database must be kept)

*****UPDATE**: After disabling every probable source of storage (database & Shared Preferences), I figured out that problem is due to **AdView**. It means once adview content is shown it adds some data to app storage, when I switch between Fragments/FragmentActivities.

Your help is really appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data are application databases and shared preferences. Share preferences are a simple key/value store, you should not abuse it to persist big data sets.

If your sqlite databases grow, the data will take up more space on the phone.

**How to solve the problem of growing data size?**

You could keep some of this data on a sever and load it on demand. Or you can try compression, e.g. [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply artworkad. I tried to see how different data influence continual progress of **data** size. I disabled Shared Preferences and SQLite db as well as savedInstanceState in code, but strangely, when I open the app and switch to setting I see that data size is already increased. (just upon fragment launch as well as DialogFragment)

Comment: Retaining states should go into cache, not app data.

Comment: ossen, did you find any solution about it? my app suffers exact same problem too.